# Phalconn Dispatcher and Loader registerNamespaces

Tags: phalcon, loader, dispatcher

I am learning Phalcon (php).
This is an example from [github](https://github.com/phalcon/mvc) using phalcon with the following folder structure
single-namespaces/
├── apps
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── IndexController.php
│   │   └── ProductsController.php
│   ├── models
│   │   └── Products.php
│   └── views
│       └── products
│           └── index.phtml
└── public
   　　└── index.php

in public/index.php, $loader registered namesapces

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(
        [
            'Single\Controllers' => '../apps/controllers/',
            'Single\Models'      => '../apps/models/'
        ]
    );
```

$dispatcher also set the namespace

```
$di->set('dispatcher', function () {
        $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace('Single\Controllers\\');

        return $dispatcher;
    });
```

If I remove `$dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace('Single\Controllers\\')`, error saying **IndexController handler class cannot be loaded**

Is that mean when loading the classes in namespaces, Dispatcher/Router will ignore the setting of loader? We must explicitly state the namespace for Dispatcher/Router?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you misunderstood purpose of [Loader](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/loader) and usage of [namespaces](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/namespaces).

When passing values to `$loader->registerNamespaces(...)` you telling the framework where to look for your classes, in our case by calling `Single\Controllers\IndexController` loader would try to include `../apps/controllers/IndexController.php`

Comment: Then whats the purpose of $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace? Aren’t they both telling the framework when to look for the classes? @Nazariy

Comment: Not quite, dispatcher has nothing to do with class autoloader, when dispatcher is is triggered with empty route it would try to use defaultNamespace, defaultController and defaultAction. So it would try to call `Single\Controllers\IndexController::indexAction` then loader would try to include `../apps/controllers/IndexController.php`

Comment: Thank for the quick response. But if the dispatcher will include IndexController.php with empty route, why it will show error ‘IndexController handler class not found’?

Comment: As I understood you have removed mapping for Single\Controllers namespace, therefore you getting an error. It happens because autoloader doesn't know where to search for Single\Controllers\IndexController class. I assume according to PSR-4 autoloader in this scenario would try to include `..\Simple\Controllers\IndexController.php` which does not exists under current folder.

Comment: So if I create the following directory single-namespaces/Single/Controllers/IndexController.php, the file can be loaded?